# Can not install xcode 7 from store, stuck on app intall

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, xcode, mac-appstore

I have a fresh OS X Yosemite, and when I went to the store to install Xcode 7 and hit the Install App button, it turned green and a loading icon appeared but after waiting a long time nothing happened. I successfully installed three apps from the store but I can not install Xcode. Please help!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide more information. How long have you been waiting for? Does the Mac App Store say "Installing"? Xcode is a very large application and can take several hours on a slow connection. Please check in your Launchpad if you have an Xcode icon with a download progress under it.

Comment: @NetherLinks i have waited about 20 min multiple times,in launchpad also nothing appears. I have MacBook Pro MJLQ2 osx 10,10,3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that I had to update OS X to 10.10.4 or later version. Problem solved!

Answer (score 4):

You can also download an Xcode `.dmg` installer file directly from [the apple developer site, downloads](https://developer.apple.com/download/). Xcode 7.2 is no longer available, at time of writing Xcode 7.3 can be downloaded, it is compatible with OS X 10.11 up.

EDIT: Looks like the XCode 7 link now just redirects to the AppStore. Perhaps the stuck on app install issue has been fixed? Anyone still getting it.

EDIT2: There's one more way to download xcode package direcly: in the bottom of [/download](https://developer.apple.com/download/) page there's a link see more downloads which points to the [/download/more](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/) page where you can download all necessary files.

Comment: That link gives `{"responseId":"3eae856c-1f6a-4244-b6c4-7da06648db0d","resultCode":1003,"resultString":"request.uri.notfound","userString":"Invalid request, Service mapping to the requested URL is not available. ","creationTimestamp":"2016-08-05T21:28:20Z","userLocale":"en_US","requestUrl":"https://developer.apple.com:443/downloads/?name=Xcode%207.2","httpCode":200,"suppressed":[]}`

Comment: Looks like they moved it to [here](https://developer.apple.com/download/). I updated the comment.

Comment: And that just gives a pointer to the AppStore

Comment: Hmm, [https://developer.apple.com/download/](https://developer.apple.com/download/) when clicked from within Safari on my OSX Yosemite takes me to the Apple Developer site in the browser. Try logging in to the Apple Developer site and then pasting the URL there. What happens?

Comment: I get a page with two entries one is Xcode 8 beta and the other is Xcode 7.3.1 which just has a link to App Store no direct download

Comment: You're right, it's been changed. Are you stuck on install, or has the problem gone away, hence the redirect?

Comment: I copied the app from my backup :) The install was still going very slowly

Comment: For edit 2 downloads, anyone have issues with the downloaded zip file? I tried Xcode 8.3, 8.3.2, both zips after download fail to unzip as if they are corrupted files.

Comment: Looks like they are ".xip" files, as per  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/242948/what-is-the-format-of-a-xip-file the format has become proprietary to Apple, it includes a signature check, so just double-click the file in Finder?