# Why developers download Xcode.xip file?

Tags: xcode

What's inside the xip file ?
Why don't download from app store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the xip file was just Xcode.app. Developers(in fact anybody) can download the xip file from [Apple Developer Website](https://developer.apple.com). Downloading from there is the same as downloading from the App Store. Probably is because if App Store is slow you can download from alternative(or some other reason). If you have a paid developer account, you can download a beta version of Xcode by downloading the xip file, which is not available from the App Store.

Comment: Does it need to be connected to internet to verify the signature ? (When decompressing it)

Comment: @WaqasShah I don't think it needs internet connection, but I actually never tried that. You can give a try if you want.

Comment: What's the meaning of verifying the signature ?

Comment: @WaqasShah You can find out more about this and xip in general in this question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/242948/what-is-the-format-of-a-xip-file

Comment: It says digital signature needs to be intact, does that mean that I should install it from the same mac where I install it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @WaqasShah Not really, the signature is stored on the file itself, so it works across Macs.